# Custom error page on SPNEGO authentication failure

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a Spring MVC REST endpoint which I successfully configured to be secured by Kerberos [as recommended](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-kerberos/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#ssk-spnego). On successful authentication everything works. The problem is when it comes to custom `401` error page.

I have it configured as (I'm spring-boot 1.3.5) as follows:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return container -> container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, "/error/401.html"));
}
```

This works nicely which I can confirm by switching to e.g. Basic auth and providing wrong credentials.

When back with Kerberos - if I access my secured endpoint with *kinit* in place everything works and in curl I see the detailed requests:

```
curl -v -u : --negotiate http://my-enpoint:8080/

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ...:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< ...
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ...:8080
> Authorization: Negotiate YIIH7 ...

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< ...
```

Now if I do *kdestroy* and do the curl again:

```
curl -v -u : --negotiate http://my-enpoint:8080/

> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host:...8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< ...
< WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

... and that's it. In this case spring returns `401` as *expected* response which is part of the handshake and therefore no error page is sent.

And here comes my two questions:

1. How can I return the 401 error page when the thing dies in the middle of the handshake?
2. How could spring possibly fallback to any other authentication as fallback (form, basic) if it *tries* to negotiate but there is no response from the client at all?

Answer (score 0):

So back with my investigation ...

This behaviour I observed is expected. The clients (browser, curl) doesn't continue with authentication if they can't authenticate. The key to provide custom page is the `SpnegoEntrypoint`. It allows to specify *forwardUrl* in it and it's javadoc says:

> Instantiates a new spnego entry point. This constructor enables
>   security configuration to use SPNEGO in combination with login form as
>   fallback for clients that do not support this kind of authentication.

The point is the forward url *any resource* which will be included in the first `401` response. You can include any page, not just form login. In my case I'm including custom 401 error page because I don't do any authentication fallback.

```
@Bean
public SpnegoEntryPoint spnegoEntryPoint() {
    return new SpnegoEntryPoint("/error/401.html");
}
```

And then the communication looks like client sends `GET` and get's back `401` response with my custom error page in body. If the client is able to negotiate it ignores the response body completely and resubmits the request with appropriate token. If it can't authenticate it displays whatever it gets back - the custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

As a response to your first question:

I had the same use case, but chose an alternative solution in which I extended the SpnegoEntryPoint with one that added a small JSON body to the response to be consumed by REST clients:

```
public class JsonSpnegoEntryPoint extends SpnegoEntryPoint {

    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException ex)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": \"Spnego negotiate, expecting to be called with negotiate-flags set\"}");
        super.commence(request, response, ex);
    }
}
```